# Composition of functions Discrete Structures, Logic and Computability

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x, y) = x + y$. Find compositions that use the functions $f$
and $g$ for each of the following expressions.

a. $x^2 + y^2$

b. $(x^2 + y^2)^2 + z^2$

Also, my professor is looking for the answer in the form like this:

$(x+y)^2= f(g(x,y))$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Start from $g(f(x),f(y))=x^2+y^2$

and you can find the solution for the other function.

Comment: OK that makes sense.  So a) would be g(f(x),f(y)) and b) would be something like (f(g(f(x),f(y)))+ f(z)?

Comment: No. $f$ is the square and $g$ is the addition. Sofor your functiion b) we have: $g(f(g(f(x),f(y))),f(z))$